# Bitmap Printing in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

how can I print a bitmap image using windows phone 8 (Silverlight app).

I'm using a Bluetooth thermal printer (Model Bixolon SPP-R200II)

excuse me ,this is my first question in Stack...

more information can provide if required.

sample code used to print text.

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

//Printer initialization command
str.Append(String.Concat((char)27, (char)64));

//Font setting
str.Append(String.Concat((char)08, (char)77, (char)0, (char)65));
//Alignment
str.Append(String.Concat((char)27, (char)97, (char)1));
//text to print
str.Append('Cash Receipt');

//Datawriter created from the socket
private DataWriter bluetoothWriter;

bluetoothWriter.WriteString(str.Tostring());

await bluetoothWriter.StoreAsync();
await bluetoothWriter.FlushAsync();
```

This I got from printer manufacture

Function: Specify bit image mode

Code: 
ASCII ESC * m nL nH d1...dk
Hex 1B 2A m nL nH d1...dk 
Decimal 27 42 m nL nH d1...dk

Range: 
m = 0, 1, 32, 33

0 ≤ nL ≤ 255

0 ≤ nH ≤ 3

0 ≤ d ≤ 255

k = nL + nH × 256 [in case of m = 0, 1]

k = (nL + nH × 256) × 3 [in case of m = 32, 33]

Description: 
 This command specifies the bit image for the mode m as to the number of dots specified by nL and nH.
• d specifies the bit image data with 1 for printed data and 0 for not printed.
• k denotes the number of horizontal dots. DPI

Comment: Windows Phone 8 doesn't support printing, sorry.

Comment: @Sumesh Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is primarily a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. As far as I can understand this question is not related to programming. I hope you can find your solution somewhere else on the web.